# How can I open a file if it crashes while I'm away?

Tags: bash, scripts

Hello I've looked up how to re-start a file if it crashes/closes automatically, but I have no experience in scripting and linux in general. I've just started a game-server and sometimes it closes because it has some errors in-game and people report them to me, so while I fix those errors, I would love to know how to restart it without being physically in my computer.

If I'm not wrong this can be done with a .bat file. Or does that only works in windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a command `YOUR_COMMAND` to always be restarted when it exits, simply put it in a loop, like

```
while true; do YOUR_COMMAND ; sleep 5 ; done
```

Note that I added a 5 seconds delay between the command's end and its restart. You can abort the loop by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal where it runs.

---

If you want the loop to only restart your COMMAND if it terminated with an exit code other than 0 (which should indicate an error/non-successful run), as @KonradRudolph suggested, you can do it like this:

```
while ! YOUR_COMMAND ; do sleep 5 ; done
```

Note that `YOUR_COMMAND` must exit with status 0  to end the loop or with status != 0 to get restarted when you use this structure.

Comment: A very simple improvement would be to query the exit status of the program and exit the loop if it was closed without error. Of course this requires the program to be well-behaved with regards to exit codes.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks, that's a good suggestion. I added it to my answer.